# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $H$ to be abelian, given a homomorphism from an abelian $G$ into $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

It's trivial to show that if $ G\cong H$, then $G$ is abelian iff $H$ is abelian.
However (Possibly trivial as well :), given that $G$ is abelian and there exists a homomrphism $\varphi:G \rightarrow H$, what additional conditions are necessary and sufficient for $H$ to be abelian as well?

Currently, for me, it *seems* it is necessary for $\varphi$ to be surjective.

Is this correct?

Comment: You can only really ask for sufficient conditions in this context, since the existence of a homomorphism can never _prevent_ $H$ from being abelian (for any abelian group $H$, there is a homomorphism $G \to H$ sending everything to the identity, so being surjective isn't _necessary_ for $H$ to be abelian, but it is sufficient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, surjectivity is a must. Every abelian group can be embedded in $S_\kappa$ for some $\kappa$ (finite or otherwise), and for $\kappa>2$ these are not abelian.

Surjectivity is also sufficient because if $\varphi\colon G\to H$ is surjective then $H\cong G/\ker\varphi$, which is the quotient of an abelian group and therefore abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Surjectivity is required as each $G$ can be embedded into $G * \mathbb{Z}$ which is not abelian.

It is also sufficient since for arbitrary $x, y \in H$

$xy = \varphi(a)\varphi(b) = \varphi(ab) = \varphi(ba) = \varphi(b)\varphi(a) = yx$ for some $a \in \varphi^{-1}(x), b \in \varphi^{-1}(y)$

Answer (score 1):

You can also find that `must` in @Asaf post in the following way. Let $h_1,h_2\in H$. If $\phi$ is surjective, so we have $g_1,g_2\in G$ such that $\phi(g_1)=h_1,~\phi(g_2)=h_2$. Now, we get $$h_2h_1=\phi(g_2)\phi(g_1)=\phi(g_2g_1)=\phi(g_1g_2)=\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)=h_1h_2$$